# Assign goBack to button for UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I am making a simple web browser, and have created a UIWebView, as well as two Buttons which each contain the text "<" and ">". I attempted assigning goBack and goForward functions to these buttons by Ctrl+Dragging onto the UIWebView, as you would if you used this official buttons. However, goBack, goForward, reload, and stopLoading are not present on the menu which appears. How would I, therefore, assign these functions to my buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  do it programmatically in your `UIButton` action.

```
- (IBAction)yourBackButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self.yourWebView goBack];
}

- (IBAction)yourForwardButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self.yourWebView goForward];
}

- (IBAction)yourStopButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self.yourWebView stopLoading];
}
```